# I have been getting this memory error on my wordpress website when I tried to covert a theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xampp, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to convert an HTML template to a WordPress theme but as soon as I do wp_enqueue_scripts for the js files I get this memory error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 314572800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\wp-includes\option.php on line 58

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 314572800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

This the whole code

```
function addjs()
{
    

    

    wp_register_script('jquery' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugin-frameworks/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' ,array(),1,1,1);
    wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery');

    wp_register_script('bootstrap' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugin-frameworks/bootstrap.min.js' ,array(),1,1,1);
    wp_enqueue_scripts('bootstrap');

    wp_register_script('swiper' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/plugin-frameworks/swiper.js' ,array(),1,1,1);
    wp_enqueue_scripts('swiper');

    wp_register_script('scripts' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/common/scripts.js' ,array(),1,1,1);
    wp_enqueue_scripts('scripts');

    wp_register_script('custom' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js' ,array(),1,1,1);
    wp_enqueue_scripts('custom');


}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs');
```

The theme works when I remove add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs');. I have tried fixes like increasing the Wordpress memory limit wp-config and I also tried doing the same in php.ini. No luck so far. It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: Look up the difference between `wp_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_enqueue_script`... one is a hook and one is a function, and they do different things

Comment: Wp register script is having 5 parameters why you have added 6

Comment: @AShah I  don't think there is anything wrong with the parameters. I was following a youtube tutorial. Now I am stuck lol for two straight days. Seems like I am the only one with this bizarre error.

Comment: @AShah Most of the time this error happens when we use a heavy plugin or a theme. Now I am suspicious about the theme I used to convert. Maybe it had something to do with this. But still how on earth can a theme use up that much memory.

Comment: @AkhilSuresh i do have the solution for this just start ob_start(); in your functions.php it will resolve your issue but not the preferred solution

Comment: @AShah I tried putting   ob_start(); in my functions.php but I am still getting the same error. No clue why this is happening.

Comment: @AShah  I read that de-registering the core-bundled version of jQuery and re-registering another JQuery version might cause the memory leak but I don't quite understand what It means. Did I added the scripts the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to add scripts to your WordPress theme

```
function regitser_scripts()
{

    wp_enqueue_script('give a name','Your script path',array(),'version',true); // true for showing it on the footer and vice versa


}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','regitser_scripts');
```

wp_eqnueue_scripts was the culprit behind the memory. Apparently there is a huge difference between wp_eqnueue_scripts and wp_eqnueue_script. And make sure the path is correct. I found the fix long ago but forgot to post this. I hope this is helpful. Read more here:https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/